# Two hilbert spaces without tensor product

Tags: hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

I haven't learnt about the tensor product and was wondering if there was a simple way of dealing with for example two 1/2 spin electrons without the tensor product.

Comment: This seems to be a legitimate question for a QM beginner.

Comment: In how much detail do you want to deal with it? There is the “vector model” that will tell you that the resulting states have $j = 1, 0$ and $j_m = +j, ..., -j$ in integer steppings. So here you can have $|1, 1\rangle$, $|1, 0\rangle$, $|1, -1\rangle$, $|0, 0\rangle$. These states are tensor products, though. Do you need to derive the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to know that for instance $|0, 0\rangle = (|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle - |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I would like to know for your example, but also in other scenarios such as for Hydrogen ion H2+ and moving from a single electron and a two proton wavefunction to combine for two electrons and two protons.